# Unknown column 'postTable' in 'field list'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and this is located in my model. I have this error Unknown column 'postTable' in 'field list' . I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

```
 public function getManufacturer()
{
    $condition = array('manufacturer_id' => $this->manufacturer_id);
    $query = $this->db->get_where('manufacturer', $condition);

    return $query->row_array();
}
public function updateManufacturer()
{
    $this->db->where('manufacturer_id',$this->manufacturer_id);
    $query = $this->db->update('manufacturer', $this);

    return $query;
}
```

And this is my controller

```
 public function updateForm()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('asset_model');

    $p = new asset_model();

    $p->manufacturer_id = $this->input->post('manufacturer_id');
    $data = $p->getManufacturer();

    $this->load->view('updateForm',$data);
}
public function update()
{
    $this->load->model('asset_model');

    $p = new asset_model();

    $p->manufacturer_id = $this->input->post('manufacturer_id');
    $p->manufacturer_name = $this->input->post('manufacturer_name');

    $status = $p->updateManufacturer();

    if ($status == true) {
        redirect('asset_management/manufacturers');
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to provide the data for update. Print out $this and you will see that it is not what you want. Data should be passed from controller eventually and method would accept those through parameters.

Comment: I updated my post, may you tell me what the problem is? @Tpojka

Comment: Your model function is wrong i think

Comment: Try use `var_dump();` for check data.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a new object of the model $p = new asset_model();... just use it as the guy has commented below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In your controller

```
public function updateForm()
     {
       $data = array();
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        $manufacturer_id = $this->input->post('manufacturer_id');
        $data = $this->asset_model->getManufacturer($manufacturer_id);
        $this->load->view('updateForm',$data);
     }

   public function update()
      {
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        $manufacturer_id = $this->input->post('manufacturer_id');
        $manufacturer_name = $this->input->post('manufacturer_name');
        $status = $this->asset_model->getManufacturer($manufacturer_id);
         if ($status == true) {
             redirect('asset_management/manufacturers');
           }
        }
    In Model

     public function getManufacturer($manufacturer_id)
    {
        $condition = array('manufacturer_id' =>$manufacturer_id);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('manufacturer', $condition);
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function updateManufacturer($manufacturer_id)
    {
       $condition = array('manufacturer_id' =>$manufacturer_id);
        $query = $this->db->update('manufacturer',  $condition);
      return $query;
    }
```